# Convert double precision to date format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date and I need add to it some days. I have a double variable with value for example 27, how can I add it to my current date?

Comment: Your question is very vague. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use datemath with the interval type...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
test=# SELECT now() + interval '27 days';
           ?column?
-------------------------------
 2017-05-10 03:44:44.807499-05
(1 row)
```

If the 27 is as an int, numeric, or double precision, use `make_interval` (cast to int if need be)

```
SELECT now() + make_interval(0,0,0,27);
SELECT now() + make_interval(0,0,0,yourcol::int);
```

Here is the signature

```
make_interval(years int DEFAULT 0, months int DEFAULT 0, weeks int DEFAULT 0, days int DEFAULT 0, hours int DEFAULT 0, mins int DEFAULT 0, secs double precision DEFAULT 0.0)
```

[@Pozs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499698/pozs) raises a valid point

> Casting like that may cause serious precision loss (i.e. the value is 27.9) -- Multiplying on the other hand may suit OP's needs better (f.ex. 27.9 * interval '1 day'). There is some rounding error here too, but the impact is much smaller. – pozs

I assumed there were no fractional days. If there were you can use this method he mentions to do the job.

```
SELECT now() + yourcol * interval '1 day';
```

Comment: Casting like that may cause serious precision loss (i.e. the value is `27.9`) -- Multiplying on the other hand may suit OP's needs better (f.ex. `27.9 * interval '1 day'`). There is some rounding error here too, but the impact is much smaller.

Comment: @pozs I'll add that to the question, I'm in CST so it's a bit late. His example had 27. I assumed there were no fractional-days. That was probably not a safe assumption.

Comment: I got it. Thank you